# Is there a way to set a minimum height on an ASP.NET Panel control?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, css

In an ASP.NET web app, on my homepage I have the following controls:

```
<asp:Panel ID="UpcomingAudits" runat="server"></asp:Panel>

<asp:Label runat="server" ID="ExpireHeader"><h2>Expiration Dates</h2><br /></asp:Label>
<asp:GridView ID="ExpirationDates" runat="server" 
 OnRowCreated="ExpirationDates_RowCreated" CellPadding="10" 
 AutoGenerateEditButton="True" AutoGenerateDeleteButton="True" 
 OnRowEditing="ExpirationDates_RowEditing" OnRowUpdating="ExpirationDates_RowUpdating"
 OnRowCancelingEdit="ExpirationDates_RowCancelingEdit"
 OnRowDeleting="ExpirationDates_RowDeleting"></asp:GridView>
```

My panel control "UpcomingAudits" is a control to which items are added programmatically in the code-behind based on items on a schedule. There is no fixed number of items--it just depends on how many are scheduled. To the right of the panel there is a toolbar with links to other pages. Whenever there are very few items on the schedule, the panel becomes very small and the "ExpirationDates" GridView bumps into the right-hand side toolbar, messing up the layout.

Is there a way that I can set a minimum size on the panel that it does not shrink beyond? I have tried setting the height attribute, but if it has a fixed height and elements are added to the panel that extend beyond the height they overflow on top of the GridView.

(**Note:** I have tagged this post with "c#" tag because that is what is utilized in my code-behind. I also tagged "html" and "css" because I could forsee a possible solution coming from one of those areas, though I am unaware of one.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `min-height` in CSS.

```
div#UpcomingAudits {min-height:300px;}
```

The downside to this is it's not supported IE6.

Known issues: IE7 does not support "inherit" as a value. IE8 has some bugs with max-width/height combined with overflow: auto/scroll.

Comment: Works exactly as requested!

Comment: It's conceivable this wouldn't work without `ClientIDMode="Static"`, unless of course that's set for the entire application already. Further, even if it does work by happenstance, if the OP ever moved the DIV, it would stop working if the `ClientIDMode` wasn't set properly.

Comment: I am working with IE8, and it didn't seem to have any issues for me. Can you elaborate more on what issues it *could* cause, as I would like to avoid them?

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud Good point. Nowadays I hope most would rather use the friendly name rather than the mangled generated name.

Comment: @called2voyage, what Chuck is saying is that `min-height` wasn't supported until IE 7 (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/min-height).

Comment: @called2voyage If IE8 is your oldest supported browser, you'll be fine. If it's not you can get around it with a polyfill.

Comment: @ChuckConway It is our oldest supported browser (thank goodness). Your solution was perfect.

Comment: @called2voyage, be sure to mark this as the answer. You may have to wait 10 minutes, but make sure to come back.

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud I am watching it like a hawk. I have 1 minute left.

Answer (score 3):

Conceivably the most straight forward way is with CSS:

```
<asp:Panel ID="UpcomingAudits" runat="server" CssClass="panel"></asp:Panel>

.panel {
    display: block;
    min-height: 100px;
}
```

where you can have any value for your `min-height`.